# Static Internet IP blocking resource loading on a website

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, routing

I have a static IP from my ISP. When I use this IP and connect to our company's quickbase.com, instance the browser is unable to load the Request URL:`https://ui-features.quickbase.com/manifests/prod.manifest.js` to load the file, which stalls and times out after 1.4mins. This makes any navigation between views impossible. Changing or flushing the DNS does nothing.

It works when I switch to a dynamic IP but it causes issues with external connections to my home server as my ISP uses IP virtualization, which is the reason I am paying extra for a Static IP. *Not sure if this is a true static IP as the cost is about $1/month*.

I have logged tickets with my ISP and QuickBase but they could not really help.

Is there something I can do to point either my ISP or QB to the possible cause or would it be possible for me to route the request for that one URL through a VPN?

Comment: Strange. With you using the static IP, run in CMD the command `ping ui-features.quickbase.com` and see if it times out. If it doesn't time out, then the problem might be with the web server of your company.

Comment: This can happen if some part of your web session is cached like cookies/tokens that your browser needs to renew, but that looks like a pretty simple request. Does it occur in another browser or a different device like your a phone? If you're unable to go directly to that URL from other devices, then quickbase (or their web hosting service etc) may be blocking your static IP

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, yes on all other devices and browsers. 
I did a tracert to a comparing the dynamic IP and and static IP and it reaches hop 24 of 25 then times out, leading me to agree that my IP is being blocked. Will log another ticket with them, specifying what is happening.